# KVM: What is stored in var/lib/libvirt/qemu

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

My Question is "What is stored in the /var/lib/libvirt/qemu folder?"
Is this used as somekind of backup folder ?

Backgroundinformation:
I have a Debian Server with a running KVM installation(+libvirt) and ~ 15 running VMs. And i want to understand why in this folder are multiple files for one VM. 
Like domain-35-[VM1] and domain-18-[VM1].

I "obtained" the Server lately and never before worked with KVM/libvirt.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I know it is the default location to store the runtime configuration, crash dumps and state files.